# the usage of "fill up"

Tags: phrase-usage

Fill the blank with the answer

> The outbreak came to global notice in late April 2009, when Mexican authorities noted an unusually large number of hospitalizations and deaths among healthy adults. As much of Mexico City shut down at the height of a panic, cases began to ____ in New York City, the southwestern United States and around the world.
>
> A. stay up
> B. crop up
> C. fill up
> D. cover up

Hello guys, the right answer is **B**, but I wonder why it can not be **C**?
Though the **B** is more fitter than **C** but is there any absolute reason why **fill up** must not be used? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Crop up' means 'occur unexpectedly'

'Fill up' means 'make completely full'.

The two terms aren't related at all, and 'fill up' isn't appropriate.

An appropriate alternative phrase would be 'pop up'.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, **crop up** is the best one. But I wonder if there does not have **crop up**, could I select the **fill up** as the answer?

Comment: no, fill up is wrong because it means 'make completely full'. For example 'hospitals filled up during COVID in New York'. They did NOT fill up during bird flu. There were just a small number of cases.

Comment: Oh, I understanded, thank you very much.